# XML or XSD file covert to c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a question. How can i convert XSD/XML to C# classes? I know that MVS(2012++) had a options (paste special -> paste xml to classes) or use xsd.exe but i need use something inside my program to convert xsd/xml to classes and work on it. Any help ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] before posting a question